# (HELP) Django Model Form does not recognize Image file

Tags: python, django, forms

I created a Form using one of my models i.e (Post), for my blog website. The form is meant for writers to post articles. In that form there is an Image attribute where the writer can upload an image. However, when i try to upload an image and post it, i get a feedback saying "field required", i think the form is not recognizing the image am trying to upload onto the the database. please help:

this is the form view from views.py:

```
def formview(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form':form})
```

this is from forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.FileField
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['category', 'title', 'body', 'image', 'author']
```

this from my models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
body = models.TextField()
image = models.FileField()
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
likes = models.IntegerField(default=1)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

this is my forms.html template:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
{% csrf_token %}

{{ form.as_p }}

<button type="submit">Post</button>
```

this is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'posts'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.homeview, name='homeview'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.postview, name='postview'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<pk>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$', views.categoryview, 
name='categoryview'),
    url(r'^author/(?P<pk>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$', views.authorview, name='authorview'),
    url(r'^add_post/$', views.formview, name='formview'),

]
```

these are the pics might help explain what am trying to say:

[Filling the form and selecting the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07odl.jpg)

[Error message after trying to post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoxaM.jpg)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def formview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form':form})
```

this `form = PostForm(request.POST,request.FILES)`,you need add FILES to PostForm

Comment: Thanks very much!..it worked...so how about the 'None'??..because now i see 'required field' all over my form even before filling it. but initially 'None' handled that unless the user fails to fill that attribute. Kindly help me out with that as well. Thanks

Comment: i have change my answer,see it again